# Display random numbers from backend to frontend(browser) one by one or dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have function that generate 10 numbers in my python script:

```
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(5)
    return json.dumps({'rand': str(random.randint(1,101))});
```

when a button is click, this above is called via ajax:

**Approach 1** - below does print only one number in console.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '/test',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(obj.rand);
        }
    })
```

**Approach 2** - adding `setInterval`, recalls function, but Im getting weird two numberspattern only

```
   94
    2
    94
    2
    ...
```

etc.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/test',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
            setInterval(function() {
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(obj.rand);
            }, 5000);
            }
        })
```

My goal is to display random numbers from backend one by one (same sleep) to UI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to get N random numbers from the server why dont you make the server code return 1 random number and loop N times on the client side using setInterval?

Comment: @balderman , hi, my goal is that every logic or function is to be done in backend, what I need is to just display it in UI one by one what is generated from backend

Comment: Got it. Try this direction: https://gist.github.com/subkitsupport/39b42a7bc42a6af5340b

Comment: @balderman, I only get one instance in the console. Do you think my backend script is correct?

`@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    for x in range(10):
        time.sleep(3)
        return json.dumps({'num': str(x), 'rand': str(random.randint(1,101))});`

Comment: @balderman, I see also that my request after printing the first number in console is always ready state 4 or done.

Comment: See here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/streaming/#basic-usage how to implement streaming on the server side.

Comment: For the client side see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: Also a good approach would be WebSockets, instead if calling Ajax in a intervall create a socket connection between your client and your server for reference check: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

Comment: Thanks @balderman for directions, Im still trying to absorb it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Fabian for suggestion. Ill give it a try too.